# Error al verificar si un punto esta dentro de un poligono (lat,long) en Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

Tengo varios puntos ubicados en un mapa de vue-leaflet ademas de unos poligonos que el usuario dibuja, estoy intentando averiguar los puntos que estan dentro de estos poligonos pero los metodos que he usado no ha funcionado, implemente la liberria: robust-point-in-polygon (https://github.com/mikolalysenko/robust-point-in-polygon) y el siguiente metodo tomada de una respuesta a una consulta parecida:

```
 * Verify if point of coordinates (longitude, latitude) is polygon of coordinates
 * https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon/blob/master/index.js
 * @param {number} latitude Latitude
 * @param {number} longitude Longitude
 * @param {array<[number,number]>} polygon Polygon contains arrays of points. One array have the following format: [latitude,longitude]
 */
 export default function isPointInPolygon (latitude, longitude, polygon) {
    if (typeof latitude !== 'number' || typeof longitude !== 'number') {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid latitude or longitude. Numbers are expected')
    } else if (!polygon || !Array.isArray(polygon)) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid polygon. Array with locations expected')
    } else if (polygon.length === 0) {
      throw new TypeError('Invalid polygon. Non-empty Array expected')
    }
  
    const x = latitude; const y = longitude
  
    let inside = false
    for (let i = 0, j = polygon.length - 1; i < polygon.length; j = i++) {
      const xi = polygon[i][0]; const yi = polygon[i][1]
      const xj = polygon[j][0]; const yj = polygon[j][1]
  
      const intersect = ((yi > y) !== (yj > y)) &&
              (x < (xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi)
      if (intersect) inside = !inside
    }
  
    return inside
  }
```

Pero en ambas salidas testeando este polígono:

[
[
4.197887,
-74.767113
],
[
4.285537,
-74.76368
],
[
4.271843,
-74.589272
],
[
4.185218,
-74.588585
]
]

Con este punto [4.1109880, -74.3938535]

La respuesta siempre es que el punto esta fuera del polígono, cuando el realidad gráficamente se muestra que esta dentro de la figura, existe algun metodo que gestiones estas coordenadas en [long,lat] de forma correcta?

Answer (score 0):

hasta donde tengo entendido un polígono debería terminar en el mismo lugar donde empieza, en tu ejemplo solo tienes 4 puntos lo cual el polígono permanece abierto de un lado esto llevaría a que cualquier punto siempre este fuera, ahora también existe una función para identificar cual es el punto mas próximo a los puntos de referencia.

Comment: Edite el array copiando el primer punto al final pero el resultado es el mismo

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo funcional de los polígonos espero te pueda ser de ayuda a mi me ayudo bastante. https://assemblysys.com/es/algoritmo-punto-en-poligono/#:~:text=Una%20forma%20com%C3%BAn%20de%20abordar,veces%2C%20el%20punto%20est%C3%A1%20dentro.